# Docker volume and Drupal

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I made a Drupal project on Docker. I started from the official images. I made a docker-compose like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - drupal:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
    env_file:
      - ./docker/env/nginx.env
    command: /bin/bash -c "sh /build_vhost.sh"

  cli:
    build:
      context: docker/cli
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DOCKER_UID: ${DOCKER_UID} # replace by your user id
        DOCKER_GID: ${DOCKER_GID} # replace by your group id
    volumes:
      - drupal:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    env_file:
      - ./docker/env/mysql.env

  drupal:
    build:
      context: docker/drupal
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DOCKER_UID: ${DOCKER_UID} # replace by your user id
        DOCKER_GID: ${DOCKER_GID} # replace by your group id
    volumes:
      - drupal:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    restart: always

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.4-bionic
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./docker/volumes/mariadb/databases:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - ./docker/env/mysql.env
volumes:
    drupal:
```

And it works, I have the Drupal files in my containers `nginx`, `cli` and `drupal`.
But if I modify it to have the files in my project, like this :

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./drupal:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80
    env_file:
      - ./docker/env/nginx.env
    command: /bin/bash -c "sh /build_vhost.sh"

  cli:
    build:
      context: docker/cli
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DOCKER_UID: ${DOCKER_UID} # replace by your user id
        DOCKER_GID: ${DOCKER_GID} # replace by your group id
    volumes:
      - ./drupal:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    env_file:
      - ./docker/env/mysql.env

  drupal:
    build:
      context: docker/drupal
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DOCKER_UID: ${DOCKER_UID} # replace by your user id
        DOCKER_GID: ${DOCKER_GID} # replace by your group id
    volumes:
      - ./drupal:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    restart: always

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.4-bionic
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./docker/volumes/mariadb/databases:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - ./docker/env/mysql.env
```

The Drupal files are not in the containers but the volume work : if I create a file in the container, I have it on my local filesystem. Before the image build the directory exists and I put the 777 perms on it.

The output when the build says that the Drupal files are downloaded and untarred.

I do not change the `Dockerfile`s between the two versions of the docker-compose.

How can I have the Drupal files on my local filesystem to version my changes, please?

Comment: A "bind-mount" volume of `./drupal:/var/www/html` is fine - it means that the directory `drupal` inside the current working dir will be exposed as `/var/www/html` in the container. However, this volume is only one way - it maps from your host to your container. **Files written to the web folder in the container at build time will not appear in the volume** because the volume overwrites whatever was baked into this folder at build time.

Comment: If you want to version control your files, then checkout the Drupal files onto your host's folder (`./drupal`) so they appear in the web folder in your container. Version control operations then should be done on your host.

Comment: Thank you @halfer, your explanations saying that the volume will overwrite the files created by the `Dockerfile` help me. I found a solution to work with this constraint.

Comment: Excellent. Note that this is not a fault though - this is working as designed.